# Use different array variables in same HTML table to show data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want the output of three arrays like this in HTML table. I stuck in this problem since 7 to 8 days. Here I am writing this static code with HTML output so that you guys can easily get what I am trying to do here. When I try to use for each then it starts looping with duplicate values. 
My PHP code is -

```
<?php 

 $variable1 = array(
        array(
        'name' => 'Jack',
        'roll' => '123',
        'class' => '4th',
        ),  
        array(
        'name' => 'Hena',
        'roll' => '124',
        'class' => '4th',
        ),
        array(
        'name' => 'Jesse',
        'roll' => '125',
        'class' => '4th',
        ),
        array(
        'name' => 'Tyson',
        'roll' => '126',
        'class' => '4th',
        )       
        );
 $variable2 = array(
        array(
        'father_name' => 'John',
        'phone_number' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        ),  
        array(
        'father_name' => 'Patrick',
        'phone_number' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        ),
        array(
        'father_name' => 'Michale',
        'phone_number' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        ),
        array(
        'father_name' => 'Dave',
        'phone_number' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        )       
        );
   $variable3 = array(
        array(
        'marks' => '89',
        'sub' => 'English',
        ),  
        array(
        'marks' => '56',
        'sub' => 'Math',
        ),  
        array(
        'marks' => '79',
        'sub' => 'Moral Education',
        ),  
        array(
        'marks' => '88',
        'sub' => 'English',
        )   
        );          

?>
```

and HTML table is -

```css
table, th, td {
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black; 
      border-collapse: collapse;
      }
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Father Name</th>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>Marks</th>
 </thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Jack</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>English</td>
   <td>89</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hena</td>
   <td>Patrick</td>
   <td>Math</td>
   <td>56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Jesse</td>
   <td>Michale</td>
   <td>Moral Education</td>
   <td>79</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Tyson</td>
   <td>Dave</td>
   <td>English</td>
   <td>88</td>
  </tr>
 <tfoot>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Father Name</th>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>Marks</th>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code example i have used a `for loop` to loop through each `index` of the first array. In that for loop the four values with the actual index are printed out. `(<?= is equal to <?php echo)`. The ternary operator (`?:`) is like an `if else` statement in short. Before it prints the values of your arrays, it checks if they are set to prevent notices of undefined indexes.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Father Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
    </thead>
    <?php for( $index = 0; $index < count($variable1); $index++ ) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= isset($variable1[$index]['name']) ? $variable1[$index]['name'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?= isset($variable2[$index]['father_name']) ? $variable2[$index]['father_name'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?= isset($variable3[$index]['sub']) ? $variable3[$index]['sub'] : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?= isset($variable3[$index]['marks']) ? $variable3[$index]['marks'] : ''; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tfoot>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Father Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```